# QR Algorithm information

Tags: numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

How can we perform 2 iterations of the QR Algorithm to the following matrix?

$$A =\pmatrix{2  & -1 & 0   \\
              -1 & -1 & -2 \\
              0  & -2 &3    
              } $$

I was stuck at identifying the a-sub 1, b-sub 2 in that they were not symmetric.

So I understand that a^(1) = 2, b^(1) = -1, but cannot seem to understand how to carry the computation of the QR algorithm for this matrix

Comment: Which algorithm are you using?

Comment: QR Algorithm is used. This is in the text, Burden and faires

Comment: You should spell things out a bit more in your question. Briefly explain the algorithm, show where you get stuck, etc.

Comment: I cannot seem to find how to categorize the an's in this case

Comment: @BuddyHolly  I advise to read http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QR_algorithm

Comment: @BorisNovikov: that didn't help answer my question. I need a setup/start on this. Could you help?

Comment: @BuddyHolly: Did you work the complete example has has in the book?

Comment: @Amzoti, I did, but that example in the book was much simpler than this one. Can you help on this problem?

Comment: I may look at it, but they look very close to me.

Comment: @Amzoti, could you do this problem? I dont see the resemblance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Given the matrix $\displaystyle A = \begin{bmatrix} 2  & -1 & 0 \\ -1 & -1 & -2 \\ 0  & -2 & 3 \end{bmatrix}$, find the $QR$ factorization using the given algorithm.

Cranking the steps in the algorithm yields the following factorization:

$\displaystyle A = Q \cdot R = \begin{bmatrix} \frac{2}{\sqrt{5}} & -\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}} & 0 \\ -\frac{3}{\sqrt{145}} & -\frac{6}{\sqrt{145}} & -2 \sqrt{\frac{5}{29}} \\ -\frac{2}{\sqrt{29}} & -\frac{4}{\sqrt{29}} & \frac{3}{\sqrt{29}} \end{bmatrix} \cdot \begin{bmatrix} \sqrt{5} & -\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}} & \frac{2}{\sqrt{5}} \\ 0 & \sqrt{\frac{29}{5}} & \left(-6 \sqrt{\frac{5}{29}} + \frac{12}{\sqrt{145}}\right) \\ 0 & 0 & \frac{17}{\sqrt{29}} \end{bmatrix}$

The eigenvalues are given by:

- $\lambda_1 = 3.911503$
- $\lambda_2 = 2.129461$
- $\lambda_3 = -2.040964$

I am going to jump start you and if this isn't enough for you to move forward, you might want to code this using some programming language (because you are asking people to step through an algorithm step by step, which is not really a math question).

We have:

$$A = \displaystyle \begin{bmatrix} 2  & -1 & 0 \\ -1 & -1 & -2 \\ 0  & -2 & 3 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} a_1^{(1)}  & b_2^{(1)} & 0 \\ b_2^{(1)} & a_2^{(1)} & b_3^{(1)} \\ 0  & b_3^{(1)} & a_3^{(1)} \end{bmatrix}$$

Choose $M = 10$ which is iterations max and we have $n = 3$, $TOL = 10^{-5}$.

**Step 1:**

Set $k = 1$

SHIFT = $0$.

**Step 2:**

While $k \le M$, do Steps 3 - 8

**Step 3:**

If $\displaystyle |b_3^{(1)}| \le 10^{-5} \rightarrow$ NO

If $\displaystyle |b_2^{(1)}| \le 10^{-5} \rightarrow$ SKIP STEP

If $\displaystyle |b_2^{(1)}| \le 10^{-5} \rightarrow$ NO

**Step 4:**

$\displaystyle b = -(a_2^{(1)} + a_3^{(1)}) = 1(-1 + 3) = -2$

$\displaystyle c = a_3^{(1)}a_2^{(1)}) -[b_3^{(1)}]^{2} = 3(-1) -[-2]^{2} = -7$

$\displaystyle d = (b^2 - 4c)^{1/2} = ((-2)^2 - 4(-7))^{1/2} = \sqrt{32}$

If $b \gt 0 \rightarrow$ NO

else YES

$\displaystyle \mu_1 = \frac{d - b}{2} = \frac{\sqrt{32} + 2}{2}$

$\displaystyle \mu_2 = \frac{2c}{d-b} = \frac{-14}{\sqrt{32}+2}$

If $n = 2 \rightarrow$ NO

Choose $s$ so that $|s - a_n^{k}| = min(|\mu_1 - a_3^{k}|,|\mu_2 - a_3^{k}|) = \frac{1}{2}(2 + \sqrt{32}) -3$

**Step 5:**

SHIFT = SHIFT + $s$ = 0 + $s$ = $s = \frac{1}{2}(2 + \sqrt{32}) -3$

**Step 6:**

For $j = 1, \ldots 3$, set $d_j = a_j^{(k)} - s$, so

- j = 1: $d_1 = a_1^{(1)} -s = 2 -(\frac{1}{2}(2 + \sqrt{32}) -3) = 1.17157$
- j = 2: $d_2 = a_2^{(1)} -s = -1 -(\frac{1}{2}(2 + \sqrt{32}) -3) =  -1.82843$
- j = 3: $d_3 = a_3^{(1)} -s = 3 - (\frac{1}{2}(2 + \sqrt{32}) -3) =  2.17157$

**Step 7:**

$x_1 = d_1 \rightarrow x_1 = 1.17157$

$y_1 = b_2^{(1)} = -1$

For j = 2, ... 3

j = 2:

$\displaystyle z_1 = \{x_1^2 + [b_2^{(1)}]^2\}^{1/2} = 1.5403191$

$\displaystyle c_2 = \frac{x_1}{z_1} = 0.760602$

$\displaystyle s_2 = \frac{b_2^{(1)}}{z-1} = \frac{-1}{1.540319} = -0.6492162$

$\displaystyle q_1 = c_2y_1 +s_2d_2 = 0.4267125$

$\displaystyle x_2 = -s_2y_1 + c_2 d_2 =$

You can take it from here, you need to finish j = 2 and then repeat this step for j = 3.

My recommendation is that you should code this up using some programming language or tool and then single step through it! If what I wrote doesn't explain it to you, nothing is going to help.

Comment: I hard a tough time on the interpmediate steps. Can you put them? That was my question, not the answer

Comment: Can you update your question showing how much you've done so we can try to make course corrections?

Comment: could you put in the detail for j = 2 and 3? I got the value of x2, but not so sure on the notation for the others. At least please provide a setup for how to continue for the j = 3 case and what's missing in j = 2. Thanks

Comment: Are you serious? You're joking, right? If you are not kidding, I am not even sure what to say.

Comment: @Amzoti: Wowwww friend! What did you do here. I am soooooo glad you did it comlete. Unfortunately, I could just give you just one plus more. :-)

Comment: @BabakS.: Thank you my friend. I am not sure what else can be done - doing that manually is so painful. I am not sure if the OP understands or does not want to work. It is a pretty involved algorithm with many variables, so looks daunting. But thank you as usual with the support my friend!

Comment: @Amzoti, I understand but still couldnt quite get the last part. I need some more details, can you please put them in?

Comment: @BuddyHolly; you have steps on the manual calculations, which you said you did not know how to do. I showed those. I provided an exact solution of the QR, the eigenvalues and intermediate calculations. If you do the calculations, you know the final answer - so can check your work from that. Good luck!

Comment: Beautiful, and bounty too!

Comment: @amWhy: This problem is UGLY to do by hand! This is one case where the algorithm should be coded up in your favorite language and then single step through it! Not sure why they were assigned this in such a fashion! Regards

Comment: Yes, indeed!! Thank goodness for the existence of such pre-coded algorithm/programs!